# realoding page in background without notifying user

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After a successful `http` request i need to reload the page  to update the view outside the ng-view so i am using `$window.location.reload()`.This is working fine but the problem is i want to reload the page silently without notifying user as the page transition works in angularjs.I also used `$route.reload()` but this did not work in this case.So is there any way in angularjs to reload the page in background so that  the user is unaware about the reload ?

```
$scope.save=function()
{
$window.location.reload();

}
```

Comment: why not just update the parts that change instead of a full page refresh?

Comment: may i know you want to be reload the page?

Comment: @SenthilRajan i am updating username  from setting page and showing this username in the sidebar which is  outside the ng-view so if i don't reload the page the update does make any effect in the sidebar!

Comment: @epascarello did it but my problem is i am binding the data outside the ng-view

Answer (score 1):

when the `http` request is resolved just run the method that loads the view again (passing the new data)

Comment: mi yes i am following your suggestion  but it only update the data inside ng-view not the ouside view

Comment: you could emit an event to tell your parent scope that the request is resolved

Answer (score 0):

You solve this with using `$rootscope`, set username with $rootScope variable,
you will update that `$rootScope` value when you get new username in `http`service

**Edit**

If in your side menu username value in text like below:

`<div id="elementId">UserName</div>` 
or 
`<span id="elementId">UserName</span>`

then
assign new user name value to userNameValue variable and do like below:

Use Jquery `$('#elementId').text(userNameValue)`

Comment: this is also work fine for pages inside ng-view but my sidebar is outside ng-view .My side bar is general layout/header for all the page which remain outside the route and ng-view

Comment: ok I got it, if you need update only in html means, then simply you can do with jQuery like this: `$('#elementId').text(userNameValue)`

Comment: My side bar:<div ng-controller="settings"><div id="elementId">{{UserName}}</div><div> and ng-view: <input type="text" ng-model="UserName"/> i am trying to bind both on edit and after submit.is there any way to apply same thing with angular instead of  jquery  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use events in Angular Js for updating portion outside of the ng-view. Like emit event when http request done & then broadcast it it or listen as per your requirement.

Comment: can you provide any example ?

Comment: Okay, i will do that, just make an plunkr for your code & i will update it by using events.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer storing user details in `$localStorage`, so that it would be stored until cache is cleared. It comes very handy to store information such as user details in the client side and it can be accessed across all controllers. `$localStorage` service can be injected into any controller and values can be set. Resetting is also easy(`$localStorage.$reset()`) to clearing information when required. You could also use `$sessionStorage`.